# Outlook logon window from gpo triggered mail signature powershell script

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm got a problem with our company wide mail signature powershell scripts com request. Everythings running fine when we start it local. But trigged by the gpo logon script the com part NewMessageSignature brings up an outlook credential window at every user-logon, that we like to solve.

Culpable code block:

```
  try{
    $MSWord = New-Object -com word.application
    $EmailOptions = $MSWord.EmailOptions
    $EmailSignature = $EmailOptions.EmailSignature
    $EmailSignatureEntries = $EmailSignature.EmailSignatureEntries
    #$EmailSignature.ReplyMessageSignature=$SignatureName
    $EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature="<INSERT SIGNATURE NAME HERE>"
    $MSWord.Quit()
  }
```

At this point the outlook.exe spawns as svhosts.exe-child, triggered by gpo-service, with the currently logged in user as user. But with strange properties in the ProcessExplorer.

[Screenshot processexplorer outlook.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymSq9.png)

I'm slightly surprised, that I found this codepart several times for this purpose and never read about similar problems.

Any hints, how we solve this?

regards
simon

Comment: There is a script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Set-Outlook-20102013-8341e049) you may want to try out.

Comment: Using a COM object to set this (trough a logon action) is asking for problems, in a lot of cases COM objects don't get cleaned up and keep an instance open. A better way to do this (in my opinion): create the HTML for this dynamically and save it to the signatures folder in appdata/roaming, this is how I did this in the past.

Comment: @bluuf, I exactly do that. The com part just activiates the signature for new messages as default.